# ZXing QRCode Scanner in Custom Layout Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

I want to create Custom View in Android for ZXing Scanner where the camera is in **portrait mode**, **custom camera view dimension**. I have a header and footer via fragment in the same view but I cannot make ZXing in Custom Layout. I did made it in full screen.

Sorry but I might be needing a bit of spoon feeding.

```
  compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
  compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
```

Above Library I used but It makes it full Screen using below Code:

Scan Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

import prizeops.com.merchant.service.CallActivityService;
import prizeops.com.merchant.service.HelperUtil;
import prizeops.com.merchant.service.PrizeService;

public class ScanActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
        integrator.setPrompt("Scan QRCode");
        integrator.setCameraId(0);
        integrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
        integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
        integrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureCodePortraitActivity.class);
        integrator.initiateScan();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int req, int res, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult intentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(req, res, intent);
        if(intentResult != null){
            if(intentResult.getContents()==null){
                HelperUtil.makeToast(this, "Scanning been Cancelled.");
                CallActivityService.gotoHomeActivity(this);
            }
            else
                PrizeService.verifyPromoCode(this,intentResult.getContents(),false);
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(req, res, intent);
        }
    }
}
```

CaptureCodePortraitActivity:

```
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity;

public final class CaptureCodePortraitActivity extends CaptureActivity {}
```

I saw few Github Posts but I couldn't understand how to customize that such as:

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java

but no help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For opening camera in portrait mode,in the manifest add the CaptureActivity as:

```
    android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    tools:replace="screenOrientation" />
```

this will replace the screen orientation=landscape which is used as default in Zxing library.

Comment: I have tried the same.but, am getting the Unresolved package journeyapps error is coming in manifest file. I have used mentioned 4 dependencies. even, CaptureActivity class package is not accepted in manifest declaration.

Comment: Have you added the dependency in gradle?Please add the dependency first for ex: compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0' in the gradle of your app.